# How to call the method in Main_Activity Class from Helper class?

Tags: java, android, class

The display function is under the Main_activity class. It displays all the files under the given directory. It is called from

```
protected void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState)
{
 ..//other code
display(path)
}

public  void display(String path)
{
   try {
    File folderX = new File(path);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(folderX.getParentFile().getName() + " / " + folderX.getName());

    final File[] folderXCHILD = folderX.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(folderXCHILD, new FileComparator());
    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, folderXCHILD,isShow);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot display the Content.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

 }
```

Now, i have another class called GridAdapter which displays the content in grid.
GridAdapter class is not an Activity itself.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder holder = new Holder();

    View rowView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridout, parent, false);

    } else {
        rowView = convertView;
    }
    holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.chk = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    if (isShow) {
        holder.chk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.chk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    final File f = data[position];

    if (f.isDirectory())
    {
      holder.img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.folderpic);
        holder.tv.setText(f.getName());
        holder.chk.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    }
    else
    {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file://" + f.getPath(), holder.img);

        holder.tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorSecond);
        holder.tv.setText("");
        holder.chk.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    }



rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                       if(f.isDirectory())
                              {
                     // I want to call the display(f.getPath()) method of MainActivity.
                 }
             });

    return rowView;
}
```

The problem is that i want to call the display() method from onClick() method inside GridAdapter. How do i proceed?

Comment: Make instance of your class in adapter class and then you can call any method from adapter class. Have you tried that?

Comment: I was thinking of that, but making an instance of Main_activity just for displaying the contents won't be an overkill? Suppose, i call the the display() method 10 times , it means that 10 instances of Main_activity would be created which is sure to make the app too heavy. Also, Main_activity contains parameters which are needed just once during start of the app. So, i suppose making instances would repeat the unnecessary thing again and again.

Comment: You don't have to create 10 instances, just 1 and reuse it again and again.

Comment: Define a custom interface in your GridAdapter class and let your main class implement it. The interface function would act as a callback method

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal Can u plz tell me how to make a custom interface? I have read about Interfaces but don't know how to implement it. So, can you give me any direction or link of any website, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @BhaveshMisri   How can i reuse 1 intance again and again? display() funtion is making a new instance of GridAdapter() class and then if i make a new instance of MainActivity() class, then again i would have to make a new instance of GridAdapter() class and this process would repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to options:
1. Cast context to an activity
2. Cast context to an interface

Looking at the line:

```
gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, folderXCHILD,isShow);
```

You are sending the context to the adapter. So inside the adapter save the reference of context and use it

```
((YourActivityOrInterface)context).YourFunctionOnActivity()
```